# ArrowDB Custom Object querying on two sets of coordinates

Tags: javascript, mongodb, appcelerator, arrowdb

I have tried asking the Appcelerator Forums but haven't got a response... hopefully someone may be able to help here - any help is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to query arrowdb custom objects to return results that are within a 5 mile radius of two sets of coordinates

My custom object looks like this:

```
{
  'name' : 'Text', 
  'coordinates': [
                   [long_1, lat_1], 
                   [long_2, lat_2]
  ]
}
```

My query object looks like this:

```
{
    'coordinates': [
        {
            $nearSphere: [ long_1, lat_1 ], 
            $maxDistance: 5/3959
        },
        {
            $nearSphere: [ long_2, lat_2 ], 
            $maxDistance: 5/3959
    ]
}
```

The response:

```
{
    code = 500;
    error = 1;
    message = "Internal server error. The Appcelerator Cloud Services Team has just been notified of this problem.";
    success = 0;
}
```